# Can't figure out foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

How can I use `foreach` to insert multiple data in my database.
 I have a drop-down menu from my `form` that will be used to add and delete rows by js function. I would like to insert data from the new row (added in the form) into my database.
This is my form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
            <input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('tableID')"/>
        <input type="button" value="Delete Row"
onClick="deleteRow('tableID')"/>
<table class="table" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<thead>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><center>Item Description</center></td>
<td><center>Price (RM)</center></td>
<td><center>Month</center></td>
<td><center>Amount (RM)</center></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tableID">
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
<td>
<select name="item_description">
    <option value="deposit">Deposit</option>
    <option value="rental">Rental</option>
    <option value="stamp">Stamp Duty</option>
    <option value="process">Process Fee</option>
    <option value="ap">AP</option>
</select>
</td>
<td><input id="price" name="price" type="text"></td>
<td><input id="month" name="qty" type="text"></td>
<td><input id="amount" name="amount" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

This is my insert query:

```
<?php
//some connection code here
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$item = array(
'item_description' => '',
'price' => '',
'qty' => '',
'amount' => '',
);
foreach ($item as $key => $value){
$value = $_POST[$key];
}
}
$last_insert_payment_id=mysql_insert_id();
$sql1="INSERT INTO payment_item (payment_id, payment_item_id, item_description, price, qty, amount)
VALUES
('$last_insert_payment_id','NULL','$_POST[item_description]','$_POST[price]','$_POST[qty]','$_POST[amount]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql1,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
?>
```

Hope someone can help me to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: So...does it work? If not, what goes wrong? Is it a MySQL error, in which case what is `mysql_error()`? Or does it run but not give you the expected results, in which case what results are you getting and what do you expect? (What exactly is your question here?)

Comment: On the subject of your code, but not your question, your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection; someone could easily hack your database and delete all your records.  You always want to escape you incoming data.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee it was run and not get any error but when i add new row table only that data will going into database, data before it will not display.

Comment: Specifying $con in one mysql call but not in the others can lead to very wonky problems if you have multiple connections open. Either use the $con option everywhere, or don't use it at all.

Comment: In your string $sql1, you should be referencing your array like so inside the single quotes: {$_POST['item_description']} (note the curly braces and the quotes around the field name). Also, you need to use mysql_real_escape_string rather than actually putting the post values in there as you are currently vulnerable to mysql injection.

Answer (score 2):

So you mean when you click 'Add row' and enter extra rows of data and then click 'Submit', only the last row gets inserted into the database?

I'm guessing that when you click 'Add Row', the following HTML is added to your table (same as the row in your question)

```
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
... and so on
```

In this case, your `$_POST['price']`, `$_POST['chk']` etc are probably getting overwritten for each row, because you now have multiple inputs with hane `chk`.

Try setting your `input id="chk[]"` instead of `input id="chk"`, and then `$_POST['chk']` will be an *array*, one for each row.

You could access each row via `$_POST['chk'][i]`.

There are also the other recommendations in the comments about making your code safe to SQL injection, and the fact that `$_POST[price]` (like you have in your SQL statement) is invalid syntax; you probably want `$_POST['price']`. (Daedalus, Marc B, Los Frijoles).